# Parsing complex text file using Unix commands

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have the following text structure which I would like to parse:

```
>Cluster 423
0   56aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:19087:2550.1... at 92.86%
1   64aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15943:81371.1... *
2   41aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:12438:91360.3... at 90.24%
3   45aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1108:13046:13861.1... at 91.11%
4   52aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1110:12260:2424.2... at 90.38%
>Cluster 434
0   64aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15723:89894.1... *
1   46aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:2:1312:1967:40935.2... at 97.83%
```

Basically, the identifier is marked with a `*` at the end and the group size is the last group number +1.

The output I want to produce would be (please note the group size at the end):

```
HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15943:81371.1      5
HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15723:89894.1      2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your file that you are parsing, where exactly is the 5 and the 1 coming from?

Comment: I've edited your question; please verify that I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a somewhat rough cut (with no error handling):

```
awk '/\*$/   { save_id = substr($3, 2, length($3)-4) }
    /^[0-9]/ { save_num = $1 }
    NR > 1 && /^>/ {print save_id, save_num+1 }
    END  {print save_id, save_num+1 }
    ' data_file
```

- On a line that ends with `*` (i.e., that matches `/*$/`),
  extract the group ID from the third word, discarding the first character (`>`)
  and the last three (`...`).
- On lines that begin with a number, save the number (i.e., the first word).
- Upon encountering a line beginning with `>`
  (but excluding the first line in the file by specifying `NR > 1`)
  or the end of the file,
  output the appropriate saved values.

Comment: ok, i tested it on my file but the output is only one id and one group size. any idea why the others are not in the output?

Comment: Is it giving you only the last one? Are the "blank" lines in your input really blank, or do they have whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, and/or carriage returns)? If they are not truly blank, they won't match `/^$/` and so the corresponding `print` statement will never be executed.

Comment: sorry, there are no blank lines in the input. I had to put them as a line change in my post was only displayed when i used double 'enter'

Comment: OK, I updated my script. Please edit your question to delete the blank line that isn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl  -F'\n' -lan00e 'print "$1\t$#F" if />(.*)\.{3} \*$/m'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[>0-9]/h;s/.*>\(.*[0-9]\).*\*/[\1 ]P /p
     $s/.*//;/^[>0-9[]/d;g;s/ .*/ 1+pc/ 
' <<\DATA | dc
>Cluster 423
0   56aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:19087:2550.1... at 92.86%
1   64aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15943:81371.1... *
2   41aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:12438:91360.3... at 90.24%
3   45aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1108:13046:13861.1... at 91.11%
4   52aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1110:12260:2424.2... at 90.38%

>Cluster 434
0   64aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15723:89894.1... *
1   46aa, >HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:2:1312:1967:40935.2... at 97.83%
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15943:81371.1 5
HWI-ST1448:257:C3V2HACXX:1:1106:15723:89894.1 2
```

It's pretty simple. It keeps a copy of the first number on the line for any line with a character. It only prints if it can successfully either remove the `*` as the last character on a line or if the line does not begin with `>0-9`. On the last line all characters are removed. So `dc` gets one `[ stuff here ]` string to `p` per `Cluster` and one little addition job when, on blank lines, `sed` pulls that saved number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep "\*" file.txt |grep -E "(?<=>)[\w+\s\W]+"|sed 's/\.\.\.\*//'
```